# what's the best way to compare selected properties in two objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to compare properties in two objects. `object2` is an array of objects and each item in the array has a lot more 'properties' than `object1` so I can't do a direct object to object comparison. I only want to compare the properties that exist in `object1` with those same properties in `object2` (and ignore properties that don't exist in `object1`).

The following works but seems very cumbersome.
(Added a sample data. Ignore that you can't `itemInArray.prop1 === ""` on a number :-)

```
var object1 =
{
  prop1: "min",
  prop2: 134,
  prop3: 121,
  prop4: 3314,
  prop5: 0
}


var object2 = [
{
    prop1: "min",
    prop2: 237,
    prop3: 563,
    prop4: 23,
    prop5: 5,
    prop6: "mrt",
    prop7: "New York",
    prop8: "usa"
},
{
    prop1: "min",
    prop2: 134,
    prop3: 121,
    prop4: 3314,
    prop5: 0,
    prop6: "mrt",
    prop7: "london",
    prop8: "uk"
  },    
{
    prop1: "min",
    prop2: 1,
    prop3: 12,
    prop4: 14,
    prop5: 2,
    prop6: "mrt",
    prop7: "Berlin",
    prop8: "Germany"      
}
];

var result = object2.filter(
    (itemInArray) =>
      object1.prop0 === itemInArray.prop0 &&
      (object1.prop1 >= itemInArray.prop1 || itemInArray.prop1 === "") &&
      (object1.prop2 <= itemInArray.prop2 || itemInArray.prop2 === "") &&
      (object1.prop3 >= itemInArray.prop3 || itemInArray.prop3 === "") &&
      (object1.prop4 <= itemInArray.prop4 || itemInArray.prop4 === "") &&
      (object1.prop5 <= itemInArray.prop5 || itemInArray.prop5 === "")
)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of `object1` and `object2` (as well as your expected result)?

Comment: You could build your checking function around `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()`. It would be easier to help if you had provided concrete examples for the objects you'll be comparing. Reference for Object.entries -> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it with something like the following:

```js
// defining initial compare rules for numbers. 
// You might want to modify them depending on the possible content.
const eq = (a, b) => a === b;
const lte = (a, b) => a <= b;
const lt = (a, b) => a < b;
const gte = (a, b) => a >= b;
const gt = (a, b) => a > b;

const obj1 = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2
};
const obj2 = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 1
};

const keyRulesPairs = {
  prop1: eq, // specifying the compare rule for the certain keyName
  prop2: gt
};

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2, keyRulesPairs) {
  return Object.keys(keyRulesPairs).every(key => { // every for all the `&&`s.
    const compare = keyRulesPairs[key];
    return compare(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
  })
}

console.log(compareObjects(obj1, obj2, keyRulesPairs));
```

As for getting only those objects from the array which are `true` by your compare rules, you just need to call with `filter` method, like this:

```
const listOfObjects = [
  { prop1: 1, prop2: 1 },
  { prop1: 1, prop2: 3 }
];

const filteredObjects = listOfObjects.filter(obj2 => {
  return compareObjects(obj1, obj2, keyRulesPairs);
})

console.log(filteredObjects)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). This way you can make your code quite generic.

View the next code sample. I will be using TypeScript so it becomes clear what types everything can be.

In a normal case:

```js
const compare = (obj1: object, obj2: object, propertyToCompare: string): boolean => {
      return obj1['propertyToCompare'] === obj2['propertyToCompare'];
}
```

You can easily loop through all the properties of an object using `Object.keys()`

```js
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(prop => {
      console.log(compare(obj1, obj2, prop));
});
```

Ofcourse in your example, you would also loop through all the objects of your array before doing the comparison. As such:

```js
obj2.forEach(obj => { // Going through all the objects from the array of objects (obj2)
   Object.keys(obj1).forEach(prop => { // Only using the properties from obj1
         console.log(compare(obj1, obj, prop)); // Comparing obj (object in array) to obj1
   });
});
```